# How to get list of servers a discord account is in

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am logging into a discord user account, and am trying to get a list of the servers that the user account is in. This is my code:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
main = "my user token"
client = Bot(main)
client.remove_command('help')

print(client.guilds)

client.run(main,bot=False)
```

This returns an empty list, even though the account is in many servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set client to Bot then print client.guilds, wouldn't this attempt to print the guilds that the bot is in?